# API calls with an Angular Service Worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I am currently tracking navigation clicks on an Angular app using the following flow -

user clicks menu item > post to activity api > success response from api received > navigate user

However this can be cumbersome and slow as the activity API may have gone cold or network latency may mean the process takes 5 or 6 seconds to complete.

I'd like to improve this process and was considering using a something like a service worker to handle the activity api call and allowing the user to navigate straight away once they have clicked a nav item.

I have been reading up on service works but at the moment it seems they are just able to cache assets and responses, not initiate api calls.

Is this possible with a service worker? If not, is their a better practice for capturing this data?

Comment: Use ngForage to store data locally after initial api call, then serve data from local. This will help in offline mode too.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear, I want the service worker to make the POST api call for me so I can navigate the user immediately and not force them to wait for a response from my activity api before changing pages.

Comment: i developed a progressive web app in angular with service worker and had similar case, but  didn't find any answer in making external POST api calls by service worker. ngForage helped.

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to `router.events`? Something like `router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(e => postDetailsToAPI(e))`

Comment: Oh that is a nice idea